# How can I access game instance data in a window procedure callback?

Tags: c++, windows

In the window procedure message processing function, I have come across a couple of things where I just have no idea what to do apart from declare a class globally so that my window procedure can see it.

Imagine I have a `Game` class that is created in the window loop function and has a handle to the window passed through into it:

```
class Game
{
    game( HWND hWnd );
    void Go();
    void ReCalculateViewportOffsets();
}

...// windows stuff and handle to window created
Game theGame( hWnd );
...// windows loop starts
theGame.Go();
```

Half-way through my game, someone changes the resolution so I need to fire a redraw with new offsets to center my viewport... I  would like to call that from my `WM_RESIZE` handler, but `theGame` has been declared as a local in my main function rather than a global. Probably a good thing? but how on earth can I get hold of `theGame` in my windows procedure function without declaring it globally:

```
case "WM_RESIZE":
    //...
    theGame.ReCalculateViewportOffsets( newWidth, newHeight );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to declare the game instance as a global, fortunately.

Windows allows you to store extra "user data" alongside each window instance you create, and you can subsequently access that data any time you have a handle to that window (which you do in your window procedure).

The functions you'll want to use are [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These functions retrieve a pointer-sized chunk of data associated with the window -- you'll probably want to use them with the `GWLP_USERDATA` constant to access the specific pointer-sized chunk of memory reserved by the window system for *your* use.

If you need to store more than a pointer-sized chunk of data, you can request extra storage bytes during the creation of your window's window class by filling out the `cbWndExtra` parameter in the class definition structure when you call [RegisterClassEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, it sounds like `GWLP_USERDATA` will be sufficient for your needs.

So, in summary:

- Create your `HWND`.
- Use `SetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_USERDATA` to store a pointer to your `Game`.
- User `GetWindowLongerPtr` to recover that pointer later.

It's also possible to pass a pointer-sized chunk of data to the window when you create it via [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That pointer-sized chunk of data will be passed to the window procedure via the `WM_CREATE` message (and that will happen before `CreateWindowEx` returns), so you can use that to store data with the window as well.

Comment: Ah, thank you wise one. I shall try this when I get home from work. That god damn no good son of a class will be accessed by my proc this evening or i'm going to be having stern talks with my nipples. I will no doubt come crawling back to this thread for on-going pestering. Thanks.